# Select the table row (only one row) and edit the content in cells

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtablewidget

With my code below, you can add/select the whole row and when edit button pressed, that print the current row on the screen.

Furthermore, previously all the rows are disabled! **Instead of print the current row, I'll be able to edit the row when selected.**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3 as sql
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, os

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.general = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.general, "General")
        cWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(cWidget)
        self.general_table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.general)
        self.setHeader()

        add_record = QtGui.QPushButton("Add Record")
        edit = QtGui.QPushButton("Edit")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(cWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        layout.addWidget(add_record)
        layout.addWidget(edit)

        self.connect(add_record, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addRecord)
        self.connect(edit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.edit)

        self.general_table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

    def addRecord(self):
        rcount_general = self.general_table.rowCount()
        self.general_table.insertRow(rcount_general)

    def edit(self):
        indexes = self.general_table.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        for index in sorted(indexes):
            print("Row %d is selected" % index.row())


    def setHeader(self):
        # General
        self.general_table.setRowCount(1)
        self.general_table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.general_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["A1", "A2", "A3"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the `setFlags` function on the item.

- For editable:

---

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable |  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled )
self.your_table.setItem(row, column, item)
```

- For not editable:

---

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | 
              QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
self.your_table.setItem(row, column, item)
```